# Is there a set partition associated with a matroid

Tags: combinatorics, matroids

It is well-known that for any set partition of X one may construct a matroid by taking the subsets whose intersections with each block of the partition has at least one element (clearly one may generalize through the usage of weights $d_i$ for eavh block).

Well, does a converse of this result hold, i.e. given a matroid is there a way to obtain a set partition in a natural way?

Comment: A set partition trivially satisfies the matroid circuit axioms, and so gives a "partition matroid" $M$. The matroid you construct is the dual matroid $M^*$ and you construct it by giving its bases. Now it seems you are asking if every matroid has a dual whose circuits are pairwise disjoint. But this is clearly false (any connected graph with two cycles will give rise to a counter example).